# An interesting, possibly complex SQL query to determine number of consecutive months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

First off thank you to everyone who helps me answer this question! I have googled and tried to learn as much as I can about recursive CTE's and other advanced features of MS SQL 05-08 but I am stumped.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
AgentID, GoalReached, MonthEndDate
360123, 1, 1/22/2011
360123, Null, 2/22/2011
360123, 1, 3/22/2011
360123, 1, 4/22/2011
360123, 1, 5/22/2011
360123, 2, 6/22/2011
360124, 2, 1/22/2011
360124, 2, 2/22/2011
360124, 1, 3/22/2011
360124, 2, 4/22/2011
360124, 2, 5/22/2011
360124, 3, 6/22/2011
```

How do I produce a table which groups by agentid and shows me only agentids that have made a level for 4 out of any 6 consecutive months? And then show which 6 month period that goal was reached?

Also, if an agent reached level 2 or higher then they also made the previous level 1. So if an agent has three level 2's and three level 1's in a 6 month period then the agent has only reached level 1.

The end result would be:

```
AgentID, LevelReached, StartDate, EndDate
360123,1,3/22/2011,6/22/2011
360124,2,2/22/2011,6/22/2011
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this one that looks like it works:

```
declare @t table ( AgentID int, GoalReached int, MonthEndDate date)
insert @t (AgentID , GoalReached , MonthEndDate )
values 
(360123, Null, '2/22/2011'),
(360123, 1, '1/22/2011'),
(360123, 1, '3/22/2011'),
(360123, 1, '4/22/2011'),
(360123, 1, '5/22/2011'),
(360123, 2, '6/22/2011'),
(360124, 1, '3/22/2011'),
(360124, 2, '1/22/2011'),
(360124, 2, '2/22/2011'),
(360124, 2, '4/22/2011'),
(360124, 2, '5/22/2011'),
(360124, 3, '6/22/2011')

select  t1.AgentID, t1.GoalReached, t1.MonthEndDate StartDate, max(t2.MonthEndDate) Enddate
from    @t t1
        inner join @t t2 
            on t1.AgentID = t2.AgentID
            and t1.GoalReached = t2.GoalReached
            and datediff(m, t1.MonthEndDate, t2.MonthEndDate) between 0 and 6  -- find any other rows for same agent within 6 months
group by t1.AgentID, t1.GoalReached, t1.MonthEndDate
having count(*) >= 4
```

I get these rows out however:

```
360123  1   2011-01-22  2011-05-22
360124  2   2011-01-22  2011-05-22
```

But I think the example output you give may be off. (The enddate of 6/22 for agent 360123 is from level 2, not 1. For 360124 that date is from level 3 instead of 2.

Let me know if this does the trick. You haven't specified how to handle cases where for instance there is a consecutive period of 9 months where a goal is reached every month. This query counts overlapping periods as two for instance so let me know if for instance a row can only be in 1 group.

Regards GJ

**EDIT**

Hi, ok did that, see below.

To remove the overlapping sequences I used a recursive CTE. I think it's the only way for a 
group to 'know' if a certain row is already in a previous group. Would be interested to see other approaches.

Personally tho I'd consider using a more 'procedural' way of going about this with a cursor or something that actually updates the rows to put them into groups. This query could be  hard to get ones head around, could be a problem for future maintenacne of the code.

So with that out of the way, enjoy! And thanks for this one, nice little jawbreaker ;-)

Rgds GJ

```
declare @t table (AgentID int, GoalReached int, MonthEndDate date)
insert @t (AgentID , GoalReached , MonthEndDate )
values 
(360123, Null, '2/22/2011'),
(360123, 1, '1/22/2011'),
(360123, 1, '3/22/2011'),
(360123, 1, '4/22/2011'),
(360123, 1, '5/22/2011'),
(360123, 2, '6/22/2011'),
(360124, 1, '3/22/2011'),
(360124, 2, '1/22/2011'),
(360124, 2, '2/22/2011'),
(360124, 2, '4/22/2011'),
(360124, 2, '5/22/2011'),
(360124, 3, '6/22/2011'),

(100, 1, '1/1/2010'),
(100, 1, '2/1/2010'),
(100, 2, '3/1/2010'),
(100, 1, '4/1/2010'),
(100, 1, '5/1/2010'),
(100, 1, '6/1/2010'),
(100, 1, '7/1/2010'),
(100, 1, '8/1/2010'),
(100, 1, '9/1/2010')
;


with 
--1: find groups of rows that are within 6 months of eachother and number the rows
step1 as (
select  t1.AgentID, t1.MonthEndDate StartDate, t2.GoalReached, t2.MonthEndDate EndDate,  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.agentid, t1.MonthEndDate order by t2.monthenddate) RowRank
from    @t t1
        inner join @t t2 
            on t1.AgentID = t2.AgentID
            --and t1.GoalReached = t2.GoalReached
            and datediff(m, t1.MonthEndDate, t2.MonthEndDate) between 0 and 6  -- find any other rows for same agent within 6 months
)
--select * from step1
-- cut sequences off to no longer than 4 rows and get rid of shorter sequences
,step2 as (
    select  * 
    from    step1 t1
    where   exists (
        select *
        from    step1 t2
        where   t1.AgentID = t2.AgentID
                and t1.StartDate = t2.StartDate
                --t1.id1 = t2.id1       -- same group(same start row)
                and t2.RowRank  = 4 -- group has to have at least 4 rows 
                and t1.RowRank <= 4 -- get rid of rows that are beyond 4
    )
)
--select * from step2 
-- collapse groups to a single row (makes next step easier)
,grps as (
    select  AgentID,            
            MAX(GoalReached) MaxGoal,
            MIN(StartDate) StartDate,
            MAX(EndDate) EndDate,
            dense_rank() over (partition by AgentId order by StartDate) GrpRank
    from    step2
    group by agentid,
            StartDate
)
--select * from sub1
-- use common table expression to remove overlap (only way I could figure out how)
,cte as (
    -- anchor to first sequence of 4 rows for each agent
    select  AgentID,
            StartDate,
            EndDate,
            MaxGoal
    from    grps
    where   GrpRank = 1

    union all 

    -- repeat to find following sequences
    select  AgentID,
            StartDate,
            EndDate,
            MaxGoal     
    from    (
                select  g.*, row_number() over (partition by g.AgentId order by g.StartDate) grp_rank
                from    grps g              
                inner join cte c 
                        on  g.AgentID = c.AgentID   -- same agent                       
                        and g.StartDate > c.EndDate -- group must start after previous group has ended (here we remove the overlap)

            )s
    where   s.grp_rank = 1  -- only add 1 group per agent for each iteration of the CTE     
)
select  *
from    cte
order by AgentID, StartDate
```

Comment: This is looking great! Thanks so much for your help, is it possible to get it down to a row can only be in 1 group? Also if there was a period of 9 months where goals were met would it be possible to select the highest goal?

Comment: Hi sorry it was bedtime yesterday and I'm at work where I only have Oracle. I'll try tonight.

Comment: ok updated to remove overlapping groups and max goal reached per group.